# Django switch flag on button

Tags: django

I have a tasklist app with a standard view and another view that filters the tasklist to show completed tasks. I have a hide button, but I don't want to make 'hidden' a property of the database coz that seems like overkill. A simple 'hidden' flag in a if statement would be enough.

```
{% if hidden==False %}
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'hide' %}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hide Completed Tasks"><i class="fas fa-eye-slash"></i></a>
{% else %}
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'home' %}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hide Completed Tasks"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
{% endif %}
```

But I don't know where to put the ternary logic that switches hidden between true and false? I would rather not resort to js coz I think it's untidy

Comment: But how will you store what tasks are hidden?

Comment: The tasks that are hidden are the tasks marked as completed in the completed field of the database. I already have a working view that hides those tasks - it's just a filter

Answer (score 0):

No need to make it overcomplicated:

html:

```
  <div class="col-3">
      {% if flag %}
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'home' %}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hide Completed Tasks"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
      {% else %}
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'hide' %}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hide Completed Tasks"><i class="fas fa-eye-slash"></i></a>
      {% endif %}
  </div>
```

Now putting a variable inside the view functions and adding the var to the rendered dictionary:

```
def home(request):
    tasks = Task.objects
    flag = False
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'tasks': Task.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date'), 'flag':flag})

def hide(request):
    tasks = Task.objects
    flag = True
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'tasks': Task.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date').filter(completed=False), 'flag':flag})
```